# Top row in excel is a main category and row under that is sub category in excel how convert to column and make it 2 related factor In "R'

Tags: r

[image of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CHLE.jpg)[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5qYN.jpg)- Skill stream top row
Columns (Employer sponsored, State Territory Nominated, Regional, Business innovation, Global talent , skill independent , distinguished talent , skilled regional , November onshore ( should be deleted)

- Family stream top row
  columns (Partner. Parent, Child ,Other family )

how to make Skill stream and Family stream as a column with subcategory infront of them ?

Expecting in R language to convert it to column
[Here is a link to download my data.](https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/dba45e7c-81f4-44aa-9d82-1b9a0a121017/resource/1133d1f9-68e7-4d2f-96fb-45104769b7dc/download/migration_trends_statistical_package_2021_22.xlsx)

Comment: Hi Reza! is this a csv or an xlsx?

Comment: can you copy and paste the first five rows of your data into the question? Thanks!

Comment: I have 2 row , first row merged , the row under that is subcateory , I want to convert merged row on the top to column with repeated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# load libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

file_path <-"~/Downloads/migration_trends_statistical_package_2021_22.xlsx"

# pull out the top column names. For some reason, this requires skipping the first 5 rows. Don't ask me why, I don't know. This is likely to change sheet to sheet, so you want to adjust it so that you get the same result.
categories <- read_excel(path = file_path, sheet = "1.1", col_names = FALSE, skip = 5, n_max = 2) %>% 
                mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_trim(str_remove_all(., "\\d+"))))

# we then turn it into a cleaned long dataframe, from a messy wide one
categories <- data.frame(
    category = na.locf(as.character(categories[1,])), # fill in the blanks with the last non-NA value
    name = as.character(categories[2,])
)

read_excel(path = file_path, sheet = "1.1", skip = 7, col_names = categories[,2]) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year, values_transform = list(value = as.numeric)) %>%
  left_join(categories)

# A tibble: 468 × 4
   Year    name                                  value category    
   <chr>   <chr>                                 <dbl> <chr>       
 1 2012–13 "Employer Sponsored"                  47740 Skill stream
 2 2012–13 "State/Territory Nominated"           21637 Skill stream
 3 2012–13 "Regional"                               NA Skill stream
 4 2012–13 "Business Innovation and Investment"   7010 Skill stream
 5 2012–13 "Global Talent (Independent)"            NA Skill stream
 6 2012–13 "Skilled Independent"                 44251 Skill stream
 7 2012–13 "Distinguished\r\n Talent"              200 Skill stream
 8 2012–13 "Skilled Regional"                     8132 Skill stream
 9 2012–13 "November\r\nOnshore"                    NA Skill stream
10 2012–13 "Skill stream total"                 128973 Skill stream
# ℹ 458 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Mark , where did you use df?

Comment: @Reza what do you mean?

Comment: @Reza would you be able to upload the xlsx file onto google drive/dropbox and share a link? I can take a look and sort it out once and for all :)

Comment: @Reza updated it so that it works with the actual data in Sheet 1.1

Comment: Sheet 1.5 doesn't have a doubled column name thing going on, so you don't need this for that. You can just use read_excel the normal way

Comment: Thanks Mark, making list from excel column which contains country name ,sheet 1.5, I faced with repeatition name of country , is that a way to create a list from column name in R ?

Comment: I don't know if I follow what you mean Reza